# Vue3 + Vite + element-plus，Encapsulating the pagination component for the second time, using props to pass values may result in a type prompt error

Tags: element-plus

```js
<template>
  <div :class="{ hidden: hidden}" class="pagination-container">
    <el-pagination
      v-model:current-page="currentPage"
      v-model:page-size="pageSize"
      :background="background"
      :layout="layout"
      :page-sizes="pageSizes"
      :pager-count="pagerCount"
      :total="total"
      @sizeChange="handleSizeChange"
      @currentChange="handleCurrentChange"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import type { PropType } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  // 数据总条数
  total: {
    required: true,
    type: Number
  },
  // 当前页码数
  page: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  // 每页显示数据条数
  limit: {
    type: Number,
    default: 10
  },
  // 每页显示个数选择器的选项
  pageSizes: {
    type: Array as PropType<number[]>,
    default() {
      return [10, 20, 30, 50]
    }
  },
  // 最大页码按钮数
  pagerCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: document.body.clientWidth < 992 ? 5: 7
  },
  // 组件布局，子组件名用逗号分隔
  layout: {
    type: String,
    default: 'total, sizes, perv, pager, next, jumper'
  },
  // 是否为分页按钮添加背景色
  background: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  // 切换时是否自动滚动到顶部
  autoScroll: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  // 是否隐藏
  hidden: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})
// 事件派发
const emit = defineEmits(['update:page', 'update:limit', 'pagination'])
// 当前页
const currentPage = computed({
  get() {
    return props.page
  },
  set(val) {
    emit('update:page', val)
  }
})
// 每页显示条目个数
const pageSize = computed({
  get() {
    return props.limit
  },
  set(val) {
    emit('update:limit', val)
  }
})

/**
 * 监听 page-size 改变
 * @param val
 */
function handleSizeChange(val: number) {
  if (currentPage.value * val > props.total) {
    currentPage.value = 1
  }
  emit('pagination', { page: currentPage.value, limit: val })
}

/**
 * 监听 current-page 改变
 * @param val
 */
function handleCurrentChange(val: number) {
  emit('pagination', { page: val, limit: pageSize.value })
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.pagination-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  
  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSRTQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t086G.png)

When I try to directly assign the value Number to pager count, I also prompt for a type error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cEH3.png)
The editor used is IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3
When I use webstorm, the same error prompt applies

Using type based declarations is possible, but that would be too cumbersome